# If the VC dimension of class H is D, does it shatter any set of size D, or just one?

Tags: vc-dimension

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension)

> The VC dimension D of class H is the largest cardinality of sets shattered by H.

Does it mean that the class shatters any set on cardinality D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation of the the definition that you mention is that if there is a set of n points that can be shattered by a classifier from H and there is not any set of n+1 points that can be shattered by the classifier, then the VC dimension of the classifier is n.

So, we cannot infer that any set of n points can be shattered by the classifier. For example, if a classifier's VC dimension is 3, it does not have to shatter all possible arrangements of 3 points. Considering all possible arrangements of 3 points, and if we are able to find at least one arrangement such that it can be shattered by the classifier, and cannot find any arrangement of 4 points that can be shattered, then VC dimension is 3.

Comment: Actually it is an explanation that a class with VC dimension k cannot shatter any set of cardinality k.